# How select from one MYSQL DB and insert it into another?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running some small Updates via CRON and execute them with PHP.

Now I want to select something from DB1 and insert it into DB2

My Problem is, that these 2 DB`s are on the same Server but with 2 different Users and it`s not possible to give 1 User permission to both DB's.

So I know this works with one user and dbconnect:

```
insert into db1.tbl1(data1,data2) values (select data2, data1 from db2.tbl2)
```

How can I do it with 2 db connects in one Loop?

Thanks

Comment: Did you code something? Just create two connections, each one by his user. Can be done by either mysqli or PDO.

Comment: How does that query even work? In my server, it will result in an error, however, `INSERT INTO table_1 (column1, column2)
SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table2` works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create two files of connection like this

```
<?PHP            
    function connect(){
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "user";
        $password = "psw";
        $database = "database";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

       if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Error conectando a la base de datos: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
        }
        else{
            $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            return $conn;
        }

    }

    function disconnect($connection){
        $disconnect = mysqli_close($connection);
    }
?>
```

and in your php file and like this

```
 require("connection.php");
    $connection=connect();
 require("connection2.php");
    $connection2=connect2();
```

obviously in your connection2.php your funtion named connect2(); and in your loop you can use the two connection

```
$query="insert into db1.tbl1(data1,data2) values (select data2, data1 from db2.tbl2)";
    $messageResult = "Good";
    $band = true;
    if(!($connection -> query($query))){
            $messageResult = "Error";
            $band = false;
    }
```

or..

```
$query="insert into db1.tbl1(data1,data2) values (select data2, data1 from db2.tbl2)";
    $messageResult = "Good";
    $band = true;
    if(!($connection2 -> query($query))){
            $messageResult = "Error";
            $band = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u r using pdo. U declare 2 different connection.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass)

$dbh2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user2, $pass)
```

Then u do this

```
$query = $dbh->prepare(select statement);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(); // you get array of data

$query = $dbh2->prepare(insert statement);
$query->execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 dB connection in two different variable and make that work .... Take value of first db in one variable and simply dump that variable into second db .... Or you can use another dB or caching dB like redis  to store one time temporary base.